# Why I am getting Segmentation fault while compiling multiple .cpp files?

Tags: c++, ipad, segmentation-fault, c++14

I am learning C++ as my first language, and I am using clang 13.0.0 compiler in iPad.

I am getting segmentation fault while compiling two files together `main.cpp` and `func.cpp` by using the command `clang++ -Wall -std=c++14 -g main.cpp func.cpp`.

These are the files.

func.cpp file

```
int add_numbers(int num1, int num2) {
    int sum{};
    sum=num1+num2;
    return sum;
}
```

func.h file

```
#ifndef _func_H_
#define _func_H_

int add_numbers(int num1, int num2);

#endif
```

main.cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "func.h"

using namespace std;

int main () {
    int num1{10}, num2{12};

    int summation=add_numbers(num1,num2);
    cout << summation << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
clang++ -Wall -std=c++14 -g main.cpp func.cpp
segmentation fault 
segmentation fault
```

But, when I include `func.cpp` in main with `#include”func.cpp”` then everything works fine.

I had gone through many solutions regarding this problem, but they are so complicated and hard to understand as a beginner

So, please provide a solution that I can understand easily.

Edit:

When I use this command, it worked

```
clang++ main.cpp -c
clang++ func.cpp -c
clang++ main.o func.o
a.out
```

Please, Explain **why** it worked and also how to get rid of the warning - [linker input unused] that generates?

Comment: What happens if you add the `-c` flag before the .cpp file names?

Comment: Still the same Segmentation fault, and a warning generated saying linker input unused.

Comment: That means the cause is in the compiler (or driver), not the linker.   Try compiling the two files separately - which will either work (in the sense of code either compiling or being diagnosed with errors) or it won't (in which case it may help localise what is causing the problem or what is crashing).   If compiling succeeds, link the object files together after separate compiling.

Comment: The files are diagnosed with errors regarding undeclared identifiers (add_number) when compiled separately, means compiler is working fine? And also I tried to link them together after compiling them separately and still the same segmentation fault occurs……and also, please can you explain why it is working when I include func.cpp in main

Comment: There's a bug in your compiler, update it or use a different build